# Regex - Maybe even in Editor?

Tags: php, html, regex, atom-editor

i never used any regex commands. and i actually think what i want is a simple-basic.

i have a list of e-mail addresses where i want to find and replace in my editor (using Atom):

Email addresses look like this: `name.surname@domain.com`

and i want to replace this with: `<a href="mailto:<insert mailaddress>">`

Can i achieve that within my Atom editor or will i need an extern script for this?

Example:

```
<p>
<strong>Name Surname</strong><br>
Main Office<br>
<br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 0000 / 11111 1111<br>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> name.surename@office.com
</p>
```

Comment: Are those emailadresses in an array? Then why not loop and concatenate?

Comment: Nope, they are already in a HTML-Markup but without mailto:links.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how exactly the list looks like?

Comment: sorry i expressed myself wrong: it's not really a list, it's within a HTML-Site with several other addressinfo (e.g. phone/fax/etc), will post example in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple pattern like `[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+` should catch any e-mail addresses you are looking for in your file.

In your search and replace, simply search for `([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)` to capture the whole address, and replace it with `<a href="mailto:\1">`. `\1` refers to the captured e-mail address.

Atom, Notepad++ or any other similair text editor shouldn't have any issues with this.

*Just a side note, maybe not relevant, but still, don't use this pattern to validate input from users, as it will validate even addresses like `-@-.-`.*

Comment: This pattern is supposed to be used for search and replace in a file of known origin with known valid addresses. Not for validation of any kind. Correct me if I'm terribly wrong, but I do believe that for this purpose it's OK to use a pattern like this, and that it will, indeed, find e-mail addresses.

Comment: tried this in atom, but atom doesn't not parse the mailaddress with \1 in the href. all other stuff is correctly replaced

Comment: @Dustin sometimes `$1` is used instead of `\1`, this is implementation dependant. Since I don't know Atom, your best bet is to refer to its user guide and look for terms like "regular expression", "search and replace", "backreference".

Comment: tried $1 and \1 - both just parse <a href="mailto:$1"> or <a href="mailto:\1"> into the replace. found some threads on github about the regex-problem itself but nothing specific.

Comment: found the mistake. i had to put the regex between ( ) - then it worked.